# How to make a child scalable and add values to it in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a chat feature in my app, with a node for chatUsers( which is created when they first use the chat feature), and a node for messages.

It's more of customer care chat, so I want every new chat to have an chatIssueId.
How can I add the issueId to the particular node (in a scalable way, that is it keeps expanding everytime a new issue is created)

[image: My db structure]

Answer (score 1):

To add the `chatIssueId` try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").push();
ref.child("chatIssueId").setValue(id);
```

This way you will have this structure:

```
chat
  pushId
      chatIssueId: id
  pushId
      chatIssueId: id
```

So you are able to create more than one `chatIssueId` every time a new issue is created. The `push()` method creates the `pushId`.

Comment: I tried the push.getKey(), 
and made a Toast to check the key I got, but it wasn't showing in Firebase

I'm a little set on keeping the nodes minimal.
If I want to make the key as the issueId, is this achievable in this manner that :
chatUsers -> chatIssues -> chatIssueId, chatIssueId, chatIssueId.....

Comment: So that the node of chatUser, has a node of chatIssues, WHICH has children issueIds

Comment: yes instead of child chat just use `child("chatUsers")` and the `push()` method it generates a random id for you to be able to use